# I need 3 columns to be displayed, which is worked, but rows are repeated twice, how can I fix it?

Tags: sql

It's (output) displaying everything twice, how can I fix it?

```
   Date     IBM_Close   GLD_Close
2019-03-18  123.040001  123.040001
2019-03-18  140.210007  140.210007
2019-03-19  127.379997  127.379997
2019-03-19  148.490005  148.490005
```

so the output would look like

```
 Date       IBM_Close   GLD_Close
2019-03-18  140.210007  123.040001
2019-03-19  148.490005  127.379997

SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM TS_DailyData
WHERE Ticker = 'IBM'
UNION
SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM TS_DailyData
WHERE Ticker = 'GLD'
ORDER BY Date;
```

Comment: ```SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM TS_DailyData
WHERE Ticker = 'IBM'
UNION
SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM TS_DailyData
WHERE Ticker = 'GLD'
ORDER BY Date;``` that's the code, it didn't post the code properly

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: Date             IBM_Close   GLD_Close
2019-03-18  140.210007 123.040001
2019-03-19  148.490005  127.379997

Comment: Do you want to show only the lastest data or the oldest data?

Comment: @lee Please include your rdbms tag, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why use UNION instead of OR?

```
SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM TS_DailyData
WHERE Ticker = 'IBM' OR Ticker = 'GLD'
ORDER BY Date;
```

I can tell from your select statement that all are the same except the value of ticker.

Comment: it still gives me the same output where 2 rows are repeted

Comment: I don't specifically need to use UNION

Comment: @lee May I know where the column ticker from? I assumed column ticker from the same table as well... Is it possible where having identical rows more than one? Please look at this db_fiddle >  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUJAFFndPVVmUMb9H1FVG3/0

Comment: @lee Also, what's your rdbms?